# vscode typescript node.js debugging inside docker breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a `typescript node.js dockerized app` inside `vscode`.

I have the following structure:

```
|api
|- src
|- dist
```

My `DockerFile` is like that:

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build typescript source
RUN npx tsc

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9229
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

My main file `server.ts` :

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import express = require('express');
import os = require('os');

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send(`<h3>It's ${os.hostname()} - (API) - ${port}</h3>`);
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[API] Server Started on Port ${port}`);
});
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

The command `yarn start` into my `DockerFile` execute `nodemon which is configured like that:

```
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": ".ts,.js",
  "ignore": [".git", "node_modules/**/node_modules"],
  "exec": "npx tsc && node ./dist/server.js",
  "signal": "SIGINT"
}
```

Here is the service configuration inside my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build: api/
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        max_attempts: 3
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 1s
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
      - node_modules-api:/usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
```

And finally my `launch.json` is as following:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to API",
      "port": 9229,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/api/",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/api/",
      "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/api/dist/**/*.js"],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "trace": "verbose",
      "stopOnEntry": true
    }
  ]
}
```

My service is starting correctly and my `vscode` debugger seems to attach correctly:

```
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/41993b9a-4af4-4106-b49f-0fe601e6571e

For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

yarn run v1.22.4

$ node src/wrapper.js

Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use

[nodemon] 2.0.4


[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*

[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,js


[nodemon] starting `npx tsc && node ./dist/server.js`


[API] Server Started on Port 8080


Debugger attached.
```

But when I'm trying to place a `breakpoint` here is the following result:

[image]

I've read a lot about the issue but none of the delivred solution worked for me.

I also dropped the log file of vscode here: https://mega.nz/file/kfZTyKoK#cZxcVJnTgzJKzHH_Xj6SVbNbVFmYlMWOwH6-OAQMfRw

If you need any extra informations, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by using `NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect` as an env var every process tried to start the inspector. But since I was starting my app with yarn, the yarn process got the inspector and my node process couldn't bind to that port.

So vscode was debugging the wrong process which is why breakpoint weren't being set correctly.

Comment: So how did you work around that? Is there other ways to pass through the argument?